# Reanimated TapGestureHandler callback with block

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-gesture-handler

What would be the way to achieve this.

callback with Animated.event works fine

callback with block gives no feedback :(

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { View, Text, FlatList, Dimensions, Image } from "react-native";
import Animated from "react-native-reanimated";
import { PanGestureHandler, TapGestureHandler, State } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
const { Value, event, call, set, add, block } = Animated;

const bottom = new Value(100);

//want to achieve something like this 
const onHandlerStateChange = block([set(bottom, add(bottom, 10))]);

// the line below Does work 
// const onHandlerStateChange = event([{ nativeEvent: { y: bottom } }]); 

const Comp = () => {
    return (
        <TapGestureHandler onHandlerStateChange={onHandlerStateChange}>
            <Animated.View style={{ flex: 1}}>
                <Animated.View style={{ flex: 1, position: "absolute", bottom: bottom }}>
                    <Text> some text</Text>
                </Animated.View>
            </Animated.View>
        </TapGestureHandler>
    );
};

export default Comp;
```

***const onHandlerStateChange = block([set(bottom, add(bottom, 10))]); *** Doesn't work here

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution that works

**Tip :**   
Understanding how reanimated evaluates nodes will be very useful

Here's the link to offical doc that might help you understand
 
https://software-mansion.github.io/react-native-reanimated/about-reanimated.html#at-most-once-evaluation-the-algorithm-

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { View, Text, FlatList, Dimensions, Image } from "react-native";
import Animated from "react-native-reanimated";
import {
    PanGestureHandler,
    TapGestureHandler,
    State,
} from "react-native-gesture-handler";
const { Value, event, call, set, add, cond, eq, block } = Animated;

const gstate = new Value(-1);
const onHandlerStateChange = event([{ nativeEvent: { state: gstate } }]);

let bottom = new Value(100);
bottom = cond(eq(gstate, State.END), [set(bottom, add(bottom, 10))], bottom);

const Comp = () => {
    return (
        <TapGestureHandler onHandlerStateChange={onHandlerStateChange}>
            <Animated.View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "pink" }}>
                <Animated.View
                    style={{ flex: 1, position: "absolute", bottom: bottom }}
                >
                    <Text> some text</Text>
                </Animated.View>
            </Animated.View>
        </TapGestureHandler>
    );
};

export default Comp;
```